# SceduleOnce Lead Conversion

Tags: sandbox

Integrate Schedule Once to Leads - Data from Schedule Once should come to Salesforce as Leads

I am new to Salesforce ,So i am not getting from to start Schedule once and from that how to convert lead in a project

Will any one helps me for Step by Step Solution.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Generally speaking, we cannot necessarily support third-party software and applications. Only salesforce.com technologies are officially supported (including ExactTarget, Heroku, Data.com, etc). However, I found some [help topics](https://help.oncehub.com/help/salesforce) that should probably answer any questions you may have regarding Schedule Once configuration with Salesforce. If you get through the configuration steps and still have problems, you should contact Schedule Once support if it's a problem with their app, and us if it's Salesforce.

Comment: That said, don't be afraid to ask here, the worst that can happen is what just happened... you'll be told of a more appropriate resource if we are unable to reasonably assist you. Please read about [ask] for more details. I wish you the best of luck in getting your situation resolved.